# Python Django manage.py runserver pop out a note pad

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning python Django through youtube. I followed the tutorial step by step: I used `django-admin startproject mysite` to create a new project, I went into the `mysite` directory and ran `manage.py runserver`. It is supposed to give me the `validating model` information, but it just poped out the `manage.py` notepad. The content of it is listed below:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os
    import sys
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

It is like the command did nothing. Can anyone tell me where I was wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Do you use a Linux or Windows system?

Comment: I am using windows. The problem is solved. I missed `python` to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be executed by python. try

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: actually the shebang at the top allows you to `chmod a+x manage.py ; ./manage.py runserver ...`

Comment: woo, it worked!! I didn't know it is just such a simple problem~ Thank you!

Comment: I believe he is on Winders